# Excel drop menu selection

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to figure out how I can populate a table from another tab onto my screen from a drop down menu selection. I've tried index, indirect, and vlookup but I am missing something somewhere. Anyone have any advice??

Thanks

Comment: Your Drop Down List is only one column or more?

Comment: Can you show an example

Comment: I'll have to get pics off the office comp tomorrow but I don't think they'll help much. Basically I'm trying to create almost a program for a roofing company that I can use for customer data entry, recap sheets, material order forms, my project list and my jr pm's running projects ect ect. I want to make a master page with a few drop down menus that will populate data entry tables, to auto fill the other pages in the workbook.

Comment: So say I want to select a residential bid sheet and recap sheet, I need the drop down menus to bring the data entry sheets I select from there to bring those to the master page. Otherwise I'm going to have the longest data entry sheet known to man.

Answer (score 0):

Usually Index, Vlookup or Pivot Table will be the path for you. By creating validation you must be sure the drop-down will only show data that can be found in the other table.